# Converting ^M Character to Whitespace without Line Break using PHP

Tags: php, unix, csv, dos

I'm trying to convert ^M character to a white space character, but having hard time doing this.

In PHP, I used "wb" option so, it wouldn't write DOS character into the file. fopen("file.csv", "wb")
It was successful, but still has line breaks instead of ^M

```
$fp = fopen("file.csv", "wb");
$description =nl2br( $product->getShortDescription());
$line .= $description . $other_variables . "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);
```

but I still see line break within the description, is there any way to remove ^M and replace it with possibly a whitespace.

Also used dos2unix, when it was in regular file "w" mode. It removes all ^M characters, but the file still has line breaks where there was ^M. I really need it to be all on one line for my CSV file to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking how to remove all the newline/line feed/carriage return characters from the description. If so:

```
$description =str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', nl2br($product->getShortDescription());
```